# Proof of conjecture concerning numerically satisfactory pairs of solutions to generalized Airy equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, numerical-methods, hypergeometric-function, airy-functions

**Question:** Given a [generalized Airy equation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.13) of the form
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-x^ny=0
$$
I conjecture that the following functions form a pair of linearly independent, [numerically satisfactory](https://academic.oup.com/qjmam/article-abstract/3/2/225/1942137) solutions for $n\in \{0,1,2,3,4,...\}$. How is this proven?
$$
A_n(x)=\frac{_0F_1(;\frac{n+1}{n+2};\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)^2})}{(n+2)^{\frac{n+1}{n+2}} \ \ \Gamma(\frac{n+1}{n+2})}-x\frac{_0F_1(;\frac{n+3}{n+2};\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)^2})}{(n+2)^{\frac{n+3}{n+2}-1} \ \ \Gamma(\frac{n+3}{n+2}-1)} \\ 
$$ 
$$
B_n(x)=\frac{_0F_1(;\frac{n+1}{n+2};\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)^2})}{(n+2)^{\frac{n+1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{2}} \ \ \Gamma(\frac{n+1}{n+2})}+x\frac{_0F_1(;\frac{n+3}{n+2};\frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+2)^2})}{(n+2)^{\frac{n+3}{n+2}-1-\frac{1}{2}} \ \ \Gamma(\frac{n+3}{n+2}-1)}
$$

**Context:** First, I already know that these functions are solutions because the [confluent hypergeometric limit functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#The_series_0F1) within them are simply the series solutions obtained through a straightforward solution attempt with a [power series method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations).

Second, I suspect that they are all linearly independent because these linear combinations appear to have a [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) given by
$$
W\{A_n(x),B_n(x)\}=\frac{2\sin{(\frac{\pi}{n+2}})}{\pi\sqrt{n+2}}
$$
I have verified this Wronskian up to $n=8$ in Mathematica, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Furthermore, just for clarity, it's worth noting that these solutions reduce for the $n=0$ and $n=1$ cases to
$$
A_0(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x} \\ 
B_0(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^x \\
A_1(x)=\text{Ai}(x) \\
B_1(x)=\text{Bi}(x) \\
$$
I have tested all of the pairs of solutions possible up to the limits of the numerical precision of Mathematica and found that $A_n(x)$ always converges to $0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ while $B_n(x)$ always diverges in the same limit. Likewise, for odd $n$ both solutions appear to oscillate exactly $\frac{\pi}{2}$ out of phase with one another as $x\rightarrow-\infty$. These are (basically) the conditions set forward by J. C. P. Miller in the linked article for numerical satisfaction.

However, I discovered these specific linear combinations through inspection. I have no idea why these constants are the ones that work. If you alter the constants even slightly, the solutions diverge wildly and no longer satisfy any of Miller's criteria.

**How could I have deduced the form of these solutions more systematically? Is there a proof to demonstrate that these specific solutions are the preferred ones?**

I know that there is a connection to the [modified Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions), but I don't really see it. There is clearly a hidden structure here that I'd like to understand and (hopefully) generalize to other, similar ODE families.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the Bessel ODE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function and changing variables $x \rightarrow f(x)$, $y^{'}(x) \rightarrow 1/f^{'}(x) y^{'}(x)$ where $f(x):=B x^n$ we end up with:
\begin{eqnarray}
y^{''}(x) + \frac{1}{x} y^{'}(x) + \frac{n^2}{x^2} (-\alpha^2 + B^2 x^{2 n}) y(x) = 0
\end{eqnarray}
If we now eliminate the coefficient at the first derivative, i.e. write $y(x):=m(x) \cdot v(x)$  where $m(x):= \exp\left( -1/2 \int \frac{dx}{x} \right) = x^{-1/2}$ then we end up with:
\begin{eqnarray}
v^{''}(x) + \left( \frac{1/4-\alpha^2 n^2}{x^2} + B^2 n^2 x^{-2+2 n} \right) v(x) = 0
\end{eqnarray}
The above ODE goes into your ODE on the top of your question if $n \rightarrow (n+2)/2$ and $\alpha=1/(n+2)$ and $B= I 2/(n+2)$.
In summary all this means that the ODE:
\begin{eqnarray}
v^{''}(x) - x^n v(x)=0
\end{eqnarray}
is solved by:
\begin{eqnarray}
v(x) := C_1 \cdot \sqrt{x} J_{\frac{1}{n+2}}(\imath \frac{2}{n+2} x^{n/2+1}) +
C_2 \cdot \sqrt{x} Y_{\frac{1}{n+2}}(\imath \frac{2}{n+2} x^{n/2+1})
\end{eqnarray}

```
In[966]:= n =.; n1 =.; n2 =.; n3 =.; Clear[f]; Clear[y]; Clear[v]; \
Clear[m]; a =.; b =.; c =.; B =.; B1 =.; g =.; d =.; q =.; x =.; k \
=.; mu =.;
f[x_] := B x^n;
subst = {x :> f[x], 
   Derivative[1][y][x] :> 1/f'[x] Derivative[1][y][x], 
   Derivative[2][y][x] :> -f''[x]/(f'[x])^3 Derivative[1][y][x] + 
     1/(f'[x])^2 Derivative[2][y][x]};
myeqn = x^2 y''[x] + x y'[x] + (x^2 - a^2) y[x] /. subst /. 
   y[f[x]] :> y[x] ;


myeqn = Collect[
  myeqn/Coefficient[myeqn, y''[x]], {y[x], y'[x], y''[x]}, Simplify]

m[x_] = Simplify[Exp[-1/2 Integrate[Coefficient[myeqn, y'[x]], x]]]
y[x_] = m[x] v[x];
myeqn = Collect[myeqn, {v[x], v'[x], v''[x]}];
myeqn = Collect[
  myeqn/Coefficient[myeqn, v''[x]], {v[x], v'[x], v''[x], x^_}, 
  FullSimplify]
FullSimplify[(D[#, {x, 2}] - x^n #) & /@ {Sqrt[x] BesselJ[1/(n + 2), 
     I 2/(n + 2) x^((n + 2)/2)], 
   Sqrt[x] BesselY[1/(n + 2), I 2/(n + 2) x^((n + 2)/2)]}]


Out[970]= (n^2 (-a^2 + B^2 x^(2 n)) y[x])/x^2 + 
 Derivative[1][y][x]/x + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]

Out[971]= 1/Sqrt[x]

Out[974]= ((1/4 - a^2 n^2)/x^2 + B^2 n^2 x^(-2 + 2 n)) v[x] + (
  v^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]

Out[975]= {0, 0}
```

Now there are connections between Bessel function and the hypergeometric functions as documented in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function for example. From that you can see that your function are related to the Bessel functions I have given above but are not just equal (i.e. you function are some sort of linear combinations of the Bessel functions I gave above). As a matter of fact the Wronskian of my functions is equal to $(2+n)/\pi$ which is different from your Wronskian.

```
In[984]:= 
y = {Sqrt[x] BesselJ[1/(n + 2), I 2/(n + 2) x^((n + 2)/2)], 
   Sqrt[x] BesselY[1/(n + 2), I 2/(n + 2) x^((n + 2)/2)]};
Det[{y, D[y, x]}] // FullSimplify

Out[985]= (2 + n)/\[Pi]
```